# Css breaks when i use position: fixed

Tags: html, css

this is my code when i try to set position to fix.i end up screwing other elements.this is part of custom css for audio player.i want to dock it to bottom just like spotify audio player.so tried making position of **.audioplayer** as **fixed** but end up screwing other parts of audio player.i tried containing it inside **custom div** and applying **position :fixed** to that but no success **:(**

Here is fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/m89L5g36/4/

```
.audioplayer{
    height: 2.5em; /* 40 */
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #333;
}

    /* player elements: play/pause and volume buttons, played/duration timers, progress bar of loaded/played */

    .audioplayer > div
    {
        position: absolute;
    }


    /* play/pause button */

    .audioplayer-playpause
    {
        width: 2.5em; /* 40 */
        height: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
.audioplayer-playing .audioplayer-playpause a:after
            {
                right: 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you trying to achieve?

https://jsfiddle.net/m89L5g36/34/

Seems like the doctype declaration and js file had some syntax errors which were causing !} to display on the output, the js section shouldn't have script tags in them, i remove them and i commented out the last function in the js file, not sure what its there.

In the html i wrapped a div around the audio

```
<div class="fixed">
    <audio src="http://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3" preload="none" controls loop></audio>
</div>
```

with the css i removed the body styling and added it to the div as follow with the position fixed.

```
.fixed{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;

  width:100%;
  padding:10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 18.75em rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5 ); /* 300 */
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 18.75em rgba( 0, 0, 0, 5 ); /* 300 */
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 18.75em rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5 ); /* 300 */

}
```